# Nodejs TypeError: Busboy is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, socket.io, busboy

I am working through some tutorials to build a chat server with file upload. I have no prior experience with NodeJS I have been following along with the instructor's code, but recently hit a snag that I cannot resolve. When trying to build the project to run test scripts via npm run dev, I get the following error. it want to recive that the file is uploaded into the uploads folder in my project :

Console log code:

```
TypeError: Busboy is not a constructor
    at C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\chat\server.js:24:20
```

in chrome Dev tools

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

answers i found online seems that i have to change the code and i have to call this instead:

```
const busboyCons = require('busboy');
...
var busboy = busboyCons({ headers: req.headers });
```

source: https://gist.github.com/shobhitg/5b367f01b6daf46a0287

i also runned this but it dont worked for me. Any help resolving this error would be greatly appreciated -- I'm kind of stuck with it.

server.js:

```
const express= require('express');
const app= express();

const path = require('path');
const http= require('http').createServer(app);
const PORT=process.env.PORT || 3000;
const io=require('socket.io')(http);
const fs = require('fs');
const Busboy = require('busboy');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.use(express.static('uploads'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
  });
  
  app.get('/css/main.css', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public" + "/style.css");
  });

  app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    req.pipe(busboy);
    busboy.on('file', ( fieldname, file, filename) => {
      const ext = path.extname(filename);
      const newFilename = `${Date.now()}${ext}`;
      req.newFilename = newFilename;
      req.originalFilename = filename;
      const saveTo = path.join('uploads', newFilename);
      file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo));
    });
    busboy.on('finish', () => {
      res.json({
        originalFilename: req.originalFilename,
        newFilename: req.newFilename
      });
    });
  });


  io.on('file', f => {
    console.log(`File by: ${f.userName}`);
    socket.emit('file', f);
 });
```

client.js:

```
const socket = io()


let textarea=document.querySelector('#textarea')
let messageArea= document.querySelector('.message_area')
let formAreaFileUpload=document.querySelector('.submitMediaFiles')
let formSubmit=document.querySelector('#form')

// preventDefault();


formSubmit.addEventListener("submit",handleFormSubmit)

function handleFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(e)
    const form = $(this);
    const formData = new FormData(form[0])
    for (const p of formData) {
      if (p[1].size <= 0) {
        return
      }
    }
    $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      url: '/upload',
      success: handleUploadSuccess,
    })
  }


  function handleUploadSuccess(resp) {
    socket.emit('file', { userName, file: { url: `/${resp.newFilename}`, filename: resp.originalFilename } });


  }
```

index.html (cutout):

```
<form id="form" style="background-color: #999999">
            <div class="contentLine">
              
            <div class="column">
              <input id="data" type="file" name="file" />
            </div>
          <div class="column last">
            <button style="float:right" type="submit">Send Multimediafile </button>
           
        
          </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        


    </section>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/client.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Have you figured out this issue? I am using typescript and earlier I thought it could be typing problem but it is something else.

busboy: 1.0.0
@types/busboy: ^1.5.0
NodeJs: 14.19.3

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation you should use busboy in this way:

```
const busboy = require('busboy');
const bb = busboy({ headers: req.headers });
```

But you said you tried and it didn't work. What error occurred then?

Comment: hi, it also said that busboy isnt a constructor, i got the tutorial from: https://iabhishek.dev/post/building-a-multimedia-chat-app-using-express-socketio-redis-and-docker-part-2

Comment: Hi, this is strange because I don't have an error. What version of busboy are you using?

Comment: Version 1.5.0, does it uploads in your example, a picture into the uploads folder?

Comment: What version are you using ?

Comment: 1.5.0 version too. No, I just tested the busboy package, here is the source: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-hvyrlt
You can run the code and see that different error is displayed than "Busboy is not a constructor"

Answer (score 1):

You can try lowering the version to 0.3.1, npm i busboy@0.3.1. I just lowered the version.